# How to check if Kusto input query parameters exist in a table?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am passing a list of node IDs to a Kusto query as input. Right now I am printing the rows of a table after checking if the rows' node IDs are in the input list. This is a way to check if the input node IDs are valid and have corresponding rows in the table. This is my current query:

`declare query_parameters(nodeIds:string);let nodes = todynamic(parse_json(nodeIds)); let serverNames = database('xyz').abc | where NodeId in~ (nodes) | project NodeId, DeviceName; serverNames;`

I would like to instead print all the input nodes, valid or invalid - and if they are valid, their corresponding rows in the table. How can I do that?

(Note: I changed the names of the database and table to preserve anonymity. Thanks.)

I've tried iff, case and !in~.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `in` operator, you can use a left outer `join`.

For example:

```
let T = datatable(NodeId:string, DeviceName:string) [
  "n1","d1",
  "n2","d2",
  "n5","d5",
  "n6","d6"
]
;
let nodeIds = '["n1","n3","n4","n6"]'
;
let nodes =
   print nodes = parse_json(nodeIds)
   | mv-expand NodeId = nodes to typeof(string)
   | project NodeId
;
let serverNames = 
   nodes
   | join kind=leftouter hint.strategy=broadcast (
       T
       | project NodeId, DeviceName
   ) on NodeId
;
serverNames
```

| NodeId | NodeId1 | DeviceName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | n1 | d1 |
| n6 | n6 | d6 |
| n4 |  |  |
| n3 |  |  |

Comment: Thanks for this! This is printing all the node IDs but not device names for the valid ones. How do I do that?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. if you need further help, try providing your input data set (or a sample) using the `datatable` operator, as shown in the answer

Comment: I got it actually never mind! It was an issue of case sensitivity. Your code works perfectly fine and I'm marking it accepted. Thank you for your help.